# Soap Webservice without using eclipse IDE in Java

Tags: web-services, rest, amazon-web-services, soap

Hi can anyone help me out to write the soap/rest webservice without using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can download SOAPUI from below and post SOAP response to webservices

https://www.soapui.org/

The response can also be fetched and there are tons of customization options available.

Comment: I need to know how to write a webservice without using eclipse.